# Kernel problem; latest version won't load; older version does. What to do?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have installed Ubuntu on a desktop my parents use. All was fine. However I think they accepted a request to update the system and now when they switch it on (the machine only has Ubuntu) they see a long list of text ending with 'kernel offset: disabled'. The list begins with 'BUG: Unable to handle kernel NULL deference at [a load of numbers].' An image of what's I'm seeing is attached to this message.

I've been able to get back into ubuntu by choosing a previous version. The updated version is 4.4.0-64-generic. The version I can get into is 4.4.0-62-generic.

I don't want my parents to have to hold the shift key every time they switch on and choose this older version [the idea of them using Ubuntu is that it's simpler than Windows, which it is, so long as these things don't happen!].

So, what should I do now? I think I have a few options but I'd really appreciate guidance.

1. Re-install from USB and start again and choose not to do updates.
2. Find a way to make UBuntu boot into the 62-generic version
3. Undo the update of the kernel [I think this is the cause of the issue, based on my newbie reading of other questions]

Any help much appreciated. [screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6k2q.jpg)

EDIT: In a terminal I typed:

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64

Then I rebooted and all's well. Phew. God bless you askubuntu! Sorry for polluting the site. But maybe it's ok to keep this posted for other newbies like me?

Comment: Answer this question yourself or mark it as duplicate. So that it doesn't appear in answered section.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you solved the problem. But this is for those who are facing similar problem, just purge the kernel which is not working.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64
```